# sending facebook notifications to multiple users

Tags: facebook, facebook-php-sdk

İ have a facebook canvas application using php-sdk and i want to send notifications to multiple users.

Using this code for sending notifications and its working.

```
$facebook->api('/USERID_1/notifications', 'POST', parameters);
```

But i want to send multiple ids so i try this code but its not working;

```
$facebook->api('/USERID_1,USERID_2,USERID_3/notifications', 'POST', parameters);
```

is there any way to do that or its not possible?

Comment: Not possible. Make separate requests (or do in a loop)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SDK doesn't support multiple recipients.

Create multiple instructions like:

```
$facebook->api('/USERID_1/notifications', 'POST', parameters);
$facebook->api('/USERID_2/notifications', 'POST', parameters);
// ...
```